# How can I check if more than one column is not null per record?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which contains 4 fields ethn_1, ethn_2, ethn_3 and ethn_4.

I need to use these four fields to:

1. Set v_ethn_code variable to the ethnicity stored when only one of these fields contains a value.
2. Set v_ethn_code variable to 'Unknown' if more than one of these columns contains a value.

Sample Data:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU599.jpg

```
CREATE TABLE users
( id number(4) NOT NULL,
  ethn_1 varchar2(3),
  ethn_2 varchar2(3),
  ethn_3 varchar2(3),
  ethn_4 varchar2(3),
);

INSERT INTO users (id, ethn_1, ethn_2, ethn_3, ethn_4) VALUES (1,'AS',NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO users (id, ethn_1, ethn_2, ethn_3, ethn_4) VALUES (2,NULL,NULL,'WH',NULL);
INSERT INTO users (id, ethn_1, ethn_2, ethn_3, ethn_4) VALUES (3,NULL,'BL',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO users (id, ethn_1, ethn_2, ethn_3, ethn_4) VALUES (4,'AS','BL',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO users (id, ethn_1, ethn_2, ethn_3, ethn_4) VALUES (5,NULL,NULL,NULL,'HO');
INSERT INTO users (id, ethn_1, ethn_2, ethn_3, ethn_4) VALUES (6,NULL,NULL,'WH','HO');
INSERT INTO users (id, ethn_1, ethn_2, ethn_3, ethn_4) VALUES (7,NULL,'BL',NULL,NULL);


╔════╤════════╤════════╤════════╤════════╗
║ id │ ethn_1 │ ethn_2 │ ethn_3 │ ethn_4 ║
╠════╪════════╪════════╪════════╪════════╣
║ 1  │ AS     │        │        │        ║
╟────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────╢
║ 2  │        │        │ WH     │        ║
╟────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────╢
║ 3  │        │ BL     │        │        ║
╟────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────╢
║ 4  │ AS     │ BL     │        │        ║
╟────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────╢
║ 5  │        │        │        │ HO     ║
╟────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────╢
║ 6  │        │        │ WH     │ HO     ║
╟────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────╢
║ 7  │        │ BL     │        │        ║
╚════╧════════╧════════╧════════╧════════╝
```

I've tried nesting conditionals to say if ethn_1 is not null, set it to this, then check if ethn_2 is not null, go back and set the variable to unknown, etc... but this won't work logically, and would be a lot more code than I think is efficient. What's the right way to check this?

Comment: Please post sample data in text format

Comment: Can you suggest a sample for formatting? I spent twenty minutes trying to format data in text format, but the lack of tabular display makes it pretty difficult.

Comment: Just write out create table insert statement for us it doesnt take long - just a sample thats it

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for an explanation on how to format your question. You can use e.g. http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/ to create "ASCII tables", then format that as "code" as explained in the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: To generate a [nice table data for question](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select id, case when nulls=3 then coalesce(ethn_1, ethn_2, ethn_3, ethn_4) else 'Unknown' end variablevalue from (
select a.*, b.nulls from users a join (
select id, case when ethn_1 is null then 1 else 0 end+  
case when ethn_2 is null then 1 else 0 end +
case when ethn_3 is null then 1 else 0 end +
case when ethn_4 is null then 1 else 0 end nulls
from users
group by id, ethn_1, ethn_2, ethn_3, ethn_4) b on a.id=b.id)a
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the prettiest, but you could use a case to find the nulls count when not null when 1 then coalese to display the single value, else unknown.

```
With CTE (Ethn_1, Ethn_2, Ethn_3, Ethn_4) as (
Select 'AS', Null,null,null from dual union all
select null,null,'WH',null from dual union all
select null,'BL',null,null from dual union all
select 'AS','BL',NULL,null from dual union all
select null,null,null,'HO' from dual union all
select null,null,'WH','HO' from dual union all
select null,'BL',null,'HO' from dual)

Select A.*, Case when (Case when Ethn_1 is not null then 1 else 0 end +
                       Case when Ethn_2 is not null then 1 else 0 end+
                       Case when Ethn_3 is not null then 1 else 0 end+
                       Case when Ethn_4 is not null then 1 else 0 end) = 1 
                 then coalesce(Ethn_1, Ethn_2, Ethn_3, Ethn_4) 
                 else 'UNKNOWN' end AS v_ethn_code 
from cte A;
```

or check for is null and count 3

```
Select A.*, Case when (case when Ethn_1 is null then 1 else 0 end+
                       Case when Ethn_2 is null then 1 else 0 end+
                       Case when Ethn_3 is null then 1 else 0 end+
                       Case when Ethn_4 is null then 1 else 0 end) = 3
                 then coalesce(Ethn_1, Ethn_2, Ethn_3, Ethn_4) 
                 else 'UNKNOWN' end AS v_ethn_code
from cte A;
```

I'm unable to find a function that results in a 1,0 for a null check which would avoid the case statements.

Resulting in:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+
| ETHN_1 | ETHN_2 | ETHN_3 | ETHN_4 | V_ETHN_CODE |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+
| AS     |        |        |        | AS          |
|        |        | WH     |        | WH          |
|        | BL     |        |        | BL          |
| AS     | BL     |        |        | UNKNOWN     |
|        |        |        | HO     | HO          |
|        |        | WH     | HO     | UNKNOWN     |
|        | BL     |        | HO     | UNKNOWN     |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/817c0f/2/0

```
CREATE TABLE ETHN
    (ID INT, ETHN_1 VARCHAR2(6), ETHN_2 VARCHAR2(6), ETHN_3 VARCHAR2(6), ETHN_4 VARCHAR2(6))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO ETHN (ID, ETHN_1, ETHN_2, ETHN_3, ETHN_4)
         VALUES (1, 'AS', NULL, NULL, NULL)
    INTO ETHN (ID, ETHN_1, ETHN_2, ETHN_3, ETHN_4)
         VALUES (2, NULL, NULL, 'WH', NULL)
    INTO ETHN (ID, ETHN_1, ETHN_2, ETHN_3, ETHN_4)
         VALUES (3, NULL, 'BL', NULL, NULL)
    INTO ETHN (ID, ETHN_1, ETHN_2, ETHN_3, ETHN_4)
         VALUES (4, 'AS', 'BL', NULL, NULL)
    INTO ETHN (ID, ETHN_1, ETHN_2, ETHN_3, ETHN_4)
         VALUES (5, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'BO')
SELECT * FROM DUAL
;
```

> Query -

```
SELECT STR, CASE WHEN CNT = 3 THEN RESULT ELSE 'UNKNOWN' END AS V_ETHN_CODE FROM (
SELECT STR, REGEXP_REPLACE(STR, ',*NA,*','') AS RESULT, REGEXP_COUNT(STR,'NA') AS CNT FROM (
SELECT NVL(ETHN_1,'NA') ||',' || NVL(ETHN_2,'NA') ||',' || NVL(ETHN_3,'NA') ||',' || NVL(ETHN_4,'NA') AS STR
FROM ETHN
  ));
```

> Output

```
STR             V_ETHN_CODE
AS,NA,NA,NA     AS
NA,NA,WH,NA     WH
NA,BL,NA,NA     BL
AS,BL,NA,NA     UNKNOWN
NA,NA,NA,BO     BO
```